# Nginx: rewrite to a file without URL changing

Tags: nginx

I have tried many options, but did not find a suitable answer. I can do this in Apache, but I can’t figure out how to do a redirect in Nginx while maintaining the URL

.../s1 changes to .../image.jpg - how to fix it?

```
location /s {
 rewrite "/s1" https://example.com/image.jpg last;
}
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/s1$ /image.jpg last;` - the first parameter should be a regular expression - and by using `https://example.com/` you are turning the rewrite into a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A redirect always changes the url, a rewrite keeps it internally.

In this case nginx is turning your rewrite into a redirect, because you specified a different server. You have 2 options:

1. If the url you want to rewrite to is local, you should simply remove the `https://example.com` part to make the url relative instead of absolute.
2. If you really want to mask a different server, then what you need to build is a reverse proxy. Nginx does have features for this.